# Скопировать 22Гб файлов

Tags: php, copy

Мне нужно с помощью php скрипта перекопировать 22Гб файлов из одной папки на сайте в другую.
Скрипт я написал, но боюсь его запускать))
`max_execution_time` поставил в `-1`

Копируется с помощью функции `copy()`
Посоветуйте пожалуйста стоит ли это делать с помощью php?
Или может посмотреть на другие языки, если да то посоветуйте какие?

Сервер под Debian

Comment: Почему это нельзя сделать простым `cp` в консоли?

Comment: И почему это нужно делать именно через сайт? Зайдите на сервер по SSH да сделайте этот самый cp в консоли. Или если прям очень нужно через сайт, то в php хотя бы запустите фоновый процесс, чтобы не блокировать работу сайта этим копированием

Comment: @AlexeyTen , мне нужно создавать иерархию папок на сервере, названия папок получаются на лету из Mysql изходя из данных в базе , а потом файлы раскладывать по этим папкам по определённому алгоритму по-этому Bash скрипт не подходит

Comment: Тогда вместо bash-скрипта запустите php-скрипт в консоли, но запускать его через сайт всё равно ни к чему

Comment: Ну всё ещё не очевидно почему bash-скрипт не подходит. В mysql можно и из консоли сходить. И ещё, вам точно нужно копирование, а не перемещение?

Comment: можно из базы сгенерить перечень команд `cp` с нужными путями и запустить это в консоли. То есть вместо релаьного выполнения копирования, вы пишите `mkdir/cp` и т.п. в sh файл какой нить. А потом руками запустите его в консоли

Comment: @teran , вот это хорошая идея, cp ведь создаст папку по полному пути?

Comment: нет, но это не проблема https://stackoverflow.com/a/1529965/1216425

Comment: @teran о да это мне подходит, благодарю Вас

Comment: я на самом деле не знаю, будет ли разница с тем чтобы просто php файл запустить в консоли )

Comment: @teran , сейчас поэкспериментирую расскажу. Страшно только проект боевой, файлы потерять никак нельзя, делаю бэкап)

Comment: вы ж копируете, куда они потеряются то? с перемещением все проще, если в рамках одного тома диска, сами данные перемещаться не будут, а только запись в структуре дерева ФС. проще в смысле, что время минимум займет